# Comparison between three integers in C

Tags: c

I want to print `1`, if the three inputs are different from each other or print `0`, if some input is repeated more than once.

This is my code:

```
int main() {
   int a, b, c;
   a = 11;
   b = 22;
   c = 11;

   if(a==b && a==c)
    printf("0");
    else if (b==c)
    printf("0");
   else
    printf("1");

   if (a > b && a>c)
    printf("1");
   else if (b>a && b >c)
    printf("1");
   else if (c>a && c >b)
   printf("1");
   else
    printf("0");

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate, why you tell us this? You are not even asking a question at all

Comment: What is the issue

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You told us what you want to do, and showed your code, good. Now what is your question?

Comment: read about the difference between `&&` and `||`, and then use accordingly.

Comment: I want to print 1, if the three inputs are different from each other 
or print 0 if some input is repeated more than once.

Comment: "I want to do X if Y" is not a question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
int different(int a, int b, int c)
{
  return a != b && b != c && a != c;
}
```

This will return `1` if all three numbers are different, else it will return 0 which must mean that there is at least one pair of duplicates.

Use it like so:

```
printf("%d\n", different(11, 22, 11));
```

which will print:

```
0
```

Comment: please check out the image
https://pasteboard.co/HC9xu3I.png

Comment: @PiyushBasak Yes? That's not the same code ... I don't understand your point.

Answer (score 2):

you can simplify your code to be

```
 if(a==b || a==c || b==c)
     printf("0");
    else
     printf("1");
```

Comment: Or even: `printf(a==b || a==c || b==c ? "0" : "1");`

Comment: @arorias Or even: `printf("%c", '1' - (a==b || a==c || b==c));` ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Or even: `printf("%d", !(a==b || a==c || b==c));`

Comment: @arorias I'm unable to top this (although I considered to replace relational operators by bitwise to improve [cache prefetching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_prefetching).) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest (when in a *playing* mood)

```
printf("%d\n", !(!!(a - b) * !!(a - c) * !!(b - c)));
```

Comment: Fancy indeed but vulnerable to `int` overflow, unlike the simple `==` checks you can make. This is exactly the way you'd do it in assembler though. Have an upvote.

Comment: @bathsheba: int overflow on `a - b`? Yes, it's possible. The multiplication operands are always `0` or `1`.

Comment: Yes `a - b` indeed is vulnerable although I really dislike that aspect of the language. But this is a great solution since it doesn't branch.

Comment: instead of multipling you could also do xoring? (which would be more obvious :D)

Comment: @hellow: hmmm, xor is not a substitute for multliplication: `1*0*0 != 1^0^0`

Comment: Indeed. How did I came up with that? :(